# Bootstrap 4 Alpha 6 Grid not responding to mobile breakpoints ( col- or col-sm ) Rails

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, twitter-bootstrap-4

In my Rails project, I'm using `gem 'bootstrap', '4.0.0.alpha6'`.
I cannot get the grid system to automatically switch to the `col- or col-sm` sizing when using multiple breakpoints in my markup.
example:

```
<div class="col-10 col-md-8 col-lg-5"></div> #stays col-md-8 even on mobile
```

Using the markup above, the grid system seems to be getting stuck on `col-md` sizing.  However, when I duplicate the code in a fiddle, all of the grid sizes seem to work as they should.
The mobile grid classes DO work in my project however, when only a single class is used.
example:

```
<div class="col-10"></div> #col-10 works when this is the only grid class in markup
```

I've had no other issues with Bootstrap in my project, aside from this one, and while I'm sure that there is a simple solution, I have been unable to figure out why this is happening.
In Chrome Dev Tools, I can see that the class `col-10` or `col-sm-10` is there, but it is just not switching over to that media query as it should when the viewport is a smaller size..the col-md breakpoint persists.

HTML

```
<div id="overlay"></div>
<div class="container-fluid bg-img">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="hero col-10 col-md-8 col-lg-5">
      <div class="inner-hero">
        <div class="col-12 hero-text text-top">Text</div>
          <div class="col-12 hero-icons">
            <i class="hero-icon"><%= image_tag('beet.png') %></i>
            <i class="hero-icon"><%= image_tag('forks.png') %></i>
            <i class="hero-icon"><%= image_tag('wheat.png') %></i>
          </div>
        <div class="col-12 hero-text text-btm">Text</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

SCSS

```
.overlay {
  position: fixed;
  width: 70%;
  height: 100vh;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: seashell;
  z-index: 2;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.bg-img {
  background: url('bgimg4.jpg') no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  height: 100vh;
}

.opaque {
  opacity: 0.7;
}

.hero {
  background: white;
  margin: 30vh auto 0;
  padding: 15px;
  box-shadow: 6px 7px 4px -3px rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
}

.inner-hero {
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 100%;
}

.hero-text {
  display: inline-flex;
  justify-content: center;
  font-family: 'Coyote';
  font-size: 2rem;
  color: black;
}

.text-top {
  padding: 40px 10px 0px;
  letter-spacing: 13px;
}

.text-btm {
  padding: 0px 10px 40px;
  letter-spacing: 8px;
}

.hero-icons {
  display: inline-flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Upgrade to Bootstrap 4.0.0 -- in this version the `col-10` will work.

Comment: upon further inspection, this doesn't actually seem to be the case.  According to what I'm reading in the docs, Alpha6 does drop the -xs infix and uses the same class system used in the newer beta version.  Also, I can tell that `col-10` is being picked up because it is showing up in dev tools...except it is still applying `col-md-` values even when it passes the smaller breakpoint.  If I ONLY have the `col-10` class, then it works fine.

Comment: Ah ok.. I will take another look

Comment: No worries.  I appreciate the help.  I've just been scratching my head on this.  I made a fiddle with the CDN and everything works fine as well.  I would wonder if it's a Rails/Gem issue, but I would expect to see a flood of similar questions if that was the case.  I even tried upgrading to Beta on a separate branch but the same issue persists.

Comment: Yeah it works for me too like the fiddle so it must be something else with the rails environment.

Comment: Hmm... strange.  I can't figure out what the discrepancy might be.  I'll have to try and reinstall the gem and see if that helps.  I suppose I can just use the CDN instead.  Thanks for looking int it though.  I'll keep you posted if I find the solution.